# Mongo find users that are not blocked

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a db in Mongo with users.  I want to retrieve all user that are not in my blocked Array. tried to filter through the results by retrieving All documents but I wonder if that's the most efficient way.  Is there a way in Mongo to find all users that are not part of an array?

Here is my User model:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true, 
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    latitude:{
        type: String
    },
    longitude:{
        type: String
    },
    blocked:{
        type: Array
    },
    friends:{
        type: Array
    },
    photo:{
        type: String
    },
    identity:{
        type: String
    },
    age:{
        type: String
    },
    herefor:{
        type: String
    },
    conns:{
        type: Number
    },
    status:{
        type: String
    }
}, { collection: 'users' });
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You probably want [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/), but you should also read what all of the [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) do in general, and understand where to apply each of them.

Comment: Have you tried $nin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like the following, assuming your blocked users array contains usernames and your mongoose model is called UserModel:

```
var blockedUsernamesArray = [];

UserModel.find({ username: { $nin: blockedUsernamesArray } }, function(err, docs) {
    // Handle result
})
```